# For creation of an appropriate SPF record, how can I find the IP address of the mail server used by a WordPress website on cPanel?

Tags: wordpress, cpanel, mail, spf

I have a WordPress website that is sending emails to me through a contact form. The From address in the emails uses the same domain name of the website.

Currently the emails are being treated as spam, probably because the SPF setting for the domain name doesn't include the mail server being used by the website.

**How can I find out the IP address of the mail server used by the website?**

Once I've got that, I can add the IP address to the SPF DNS record for the domain.

Comment: Unless you have a complex server setup, I'm pretty sure the mail server IP address is the same as the web server IP address (everything run from one remote computer).

Comment: There are a number of online MX lookup sites you can use, like [this](https://mxtoolbox.com/) one. If you enter in your domain, it will report back the hostname and IP address. You can also do an SPF record lookup there too (from the pulldown menu that appear after you do the MX lookup).

Comment: @Mike The hosting service I'm most familiar with uses 2 different mail servers (one is a failover I think) that are different to the servers the websites are hosted on. I don't know how common that is though.

Comment: @dan as per my comment to Mike, I don't think that works. Perhaps when the website sends an email, there's some details in the raw email data?

Comment: @HighlyIrregular Did you look at the link in my comment, it has other options, including sending an email from your site to view a [full Deliverability Report](https://mxtoolbox.com/deliverability) that will: `analyze the headers, the blacklist reputation of your outbound IP address, and your SPF records`. I'd suggest spending some time using that tool. Also, did you just ask your hosting service for help?

Comment: @Mike the webserver and mail servers rarely run on the same IP address in my experience.   The only time I might expect that is if you were running both services yourself on a dedicated host or VPS.     Most shared hosting companies have separate servers for mail and web.